# The image is working well on local server but failed to load on remote server?

Tags: reactjs, image

I am working on a react js project, and my image resources are put on the public/images folder. The images are displayed properly when working on local server, however, they does not behave well when the project is deployed on remote server.

I am really stuck with this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks for your time.

[image]
[image]

Comment: show me the url of image in the network tab,in local as well as remote, it's a path issue well

Comment: What is the url for img src when not used locally?

Comment: <img src="images/aa@3x-8 1.png" />
I put the image in the <img> tag like this, sorry if i misunderstood.

Comment: Are you sure you approve all permissions on the remote server? that may be the case

Comment: move your images folder to src folder

Answer (score 0):

You this pattern to access images from public folder.

```
<img src={window.location.origin + '/yourPathHere.jpg'} />
```